# Serializer ignores properties that use another serialized property

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I am working on an endpoint in asp.net that serializes and returns some data, using the default serializer.

The consuming applications are transitioning between changing names for properties (in other words, some existing applications are using names like ...Vat; while newer ones are using ...Tax. I therefore need to keep both names in the response for the moment, until these changes are complete.

The return type is IList.

```
public class Product
{
    ...
    public decimal PriceIncVat { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIncTax { get { return PriceIncVat; } }
    public int TaxCode { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

However, when I examine the response in fiddler, only the PriceIncVat property exists in the json list of products.

I can't think of any reason why the above wouldn't work. I added TaxCode at the same time as PriceIncTax, and it is returned, so I know the code of the endpoint is up to date.

And on the client side of a newer client project we have:

```
public class ProductDto
{
    ...
    public decimal PriceIncTax { get; set; }
    public string TaxCode { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Very confused here.

Comment: Btw. what JSON serializer do you use?

Comment: The default one - I haven't implemented my own.

Answer (score 0):

The serializer *assumes* you will need to deserialize the data some time. Hence by default only properties with a getter *and* a setter are considered.

When using the `DataContractJsonSerializer`, it's possible to turn on serialization of read-only properties using the [`SerializeReadOnlyTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.serializereadonlytypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property (despite its rather misleading name).

Side note: Check-out the [Json.NET serializer](http://james.newtonking.com/json), which gives more options and better control over the (de)serialization process.

Comment: Interesting. If this is the case, do you know how I can get around it - is there an attribute I can use to mark the property, for example?